# Chrome support for CTAP2 authenticator with BLE transport

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, webauthn

I'm trying to implement a WebAuthn authenticator with a BLE transport, for a custom authenticator on Android and iOS. However, my research regarding support of CTAP2 authenticator thru BLE support in Chrome has been inconclusive. Although caniuse [states that Chrome has full support](https://caniuse.com/webauthn), Chromestatus seems to [state that BLE support was removed from Chrome in 2020](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4895365459345408).

Due to this ambiguity, I'm unsure if I should go ahead with my implementation as I do not want to waste a whole lot of time. Which one of these are accurate? Does chrome has full WebAuthn support (which I presume includes CTAP2 over BLE), or is it specifically missing support for CTAP2 over BLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on trying to add Chrome support for Bluetooth authenticators, and made the decision not to ship.

The deprecation only affected Chrome on Mac and Chrome OS. On other platforms (Windows, Android), Chrome interacts with the platform's WebAuthn APIs. You can pair an authenticator to a Windows machine over Bluetooth and it will be available to Chrome.

Comment: Ah that's a bummer. So Chrome no longer supports CTAP2 authenticators thru BLE on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth-based FIDO authenticators typically get paired at the OS level. Chrome only handles transports if the underlying platform can't handle it itself.

Comment: My iPhone and Mac dont pair over Bluetooth anymore. So, does that mean Chrome will be able to handle BLE transports between iPhone and Mac if I develop an iOS CTAP2 authenticator application?

Comment: While Bluetooth is technically a supported transport for CTAP2, it is quite unreliable and has a poor user experience. I would not expect to see first class support remain across the ecosystem. You should create a passkey provider application that uses native platform APIs, which can then use FIDO Cross-Device Authentication.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Apparently, for apps which still support lower iOS versions like iOS 15 and 16, passkey provider approach is a no-go as passkey provider is supported starting iOS 17 itself. To add to that, iOS' passkey provider does not support attestation.